# Convert pure php format <a href> into wp coding format

Tags: wordpress

Pure php :

```
<a href="author.php/?author_name=<?php echo $author_name; ?>">Test</a>
```

WP Coding :

```
<a href="<?php xtocky_get_template('author', '', array('author_name' => get_the_author();) );?>">Test</a>
```

It doesnt give any error but my website keep loading, cannot open. How to convert pure php into wp coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't think there is any function called  xtocky_get_template :

if you just want to get get template trying the following:

```
  <a href="<?php get_template('author', '', array('author_name' => 
   get_the_author();) );?>">Test</a>
```

Comment: xtocky_get_template is my theme function, anyway i tried replace it with your code, but still problem the same. Webpage keep loading, cannot open.

Comment: No. I put this code at content-product.php.
I think get_template('author') is the same as jquery call other page content and display the content onto current page right?

I guess get_template('author') cannot use on <a href="">. What is suitable wp coding that suit to use on <a href=""> ?

Comment: should be something like <a href="%s">%s</a>', get_authorProfile_url( $author->ID )>

Comment: try remove the comma after get_the_author();

Comment: i just test the code and it's should work fine as follow:

<a href="<?php get_template('author', '', array('author_name' => get_the_author() ) );?>">Test</a>

Comment: now my webpage is loaded without error, but dont know why cannot get the content from author.php page... I know it is out of topic here, so i marked ur answer correct since it solved page stuck in loading problem. Thanks.

Comment: no problem as i understand from your code you want to get the author name and link to his page am i correct?

Comment: no. I just want to convert pure php <a href="author.php/?author_name=<?php echo $author_name; ?>">Test</a>

It is creating a link that redirect to the page www.author.php/?author_name=zac1987

then, in page author.php can use $_GET['author_name'] to get value "zac1987"

Comment: so you mean that you need to get the author link who wrote the specific post if i understand correct then you need to use 

get_the_author_link();

Comment: YES! get_the_author_link(); is what i want. Thank you. I read the documentation about get_the_author_link();, it shows if author didnt set home page yet, then get_the_author_link(); return author name only, won't return as a link that will redirect to author's homepage. I think wp doesn't has default author's homepage right? That's why I have create author.php as author's homepage, may I know how to let get_the_author_link(); know author.php is author's homepage?